# Can I leave cauliflower florets in batter overnight for making Gobi Manchurian?

Tags: indian-cuisine, deep-frying, chinese-cuisine

So I have this potluck party coming up tomorrow and I am supposed to bring an Indo Chinese version of these dishes - Gobi Manchurian and Veg Hakka Noodles! Since I am the only one who will be doing all the cooking myself for 10-15 people, I want to work out few things overnight so that tomorrow morning I am not stressed out by the scale and volume and can be ready in time with my dishes for lunch!

So what I really want to figure out is what happens to Gobi aka Cauliflower florets if I leave it on batter overnight and just deep fry the next morning! Will it retain the crunch and flavours required for Manchurian or will it become gooey and spread apart. I have left chicken overnight and fried it the next day but I am really not sure about this. Any suggestions??

Comment: As someone from the area I'm glad and surprised that my home town dish is popular so far away. Yes, the crunch is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I seem to have figured out. If you leave florets in the batter overnight, the veggie will loose all the water and make the batter very very thin from what you would actually need for deep frying. So the answer is no. It shouldn't be done!!

Comment: that's right. I would not even cut the cauliflower so much prior to cooking. It looses its firm texture and never leave it in batter, they become soggy and as you said release water.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can  leave it overnight. We often use carrot cauliflower beans for making crispy vegetables and leave them in batter for 4 - 5 hours. Don't boil the cauliflower florets to add in the batter and  make little  more thick batter.  Generally cauliflower don't loose water. 
Otherwise you can deep fry the cauliflower florets till 50% done and cool them  completely and refrigerate. Next day fry again till crisp and done.[image]
https://www.hassanchef.com/2019/12/quick-gobi-cauliflower-manchurian.html